# SpringBoot2: snake_case to camelCase payload mapping via xsd

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb, java-11, snakecasing

My app was on Java8 Spring MVC and I'm migrating it to Java11 Spring Boot application.

I use Jaxb generated classes from an `.xsd` file for the model classes for Input JSON requests where one of the the incoming payload is `snake_case` based and the generated classes are in `camelCase`. Other endpoints are in CamelCase or PascalCase that is workins fine.

In older version, the input payload used to get mapped to the model classes but in spring boot, I am finding the payload attributes of snake_case one as null.

To summarize, `event_name` becomes `eventName` in the java class and is not picking values is `event_name` attribute in payload.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
   ...
   ...
   <xsd:element name="sampleClassName">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                ...
                <xsd:element name="event_name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
                ...
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
   ...
</xsd:schema>
```

The autogenerated class gets the following annotation:

```
@XmlElement(name = "event_name", required = true)
protected String eventName;
```

My dependencies in gradle:

```
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.9"
xjc "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.6"
xjc "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.6"
compile "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.6"
```

Please suggest what could be going wrong. I referred to other posts and tried the following dependencies as well but no luck.

```
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.9.4"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.9.4"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.4"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.4"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.4"
compile(group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-xml', version: '2.6.3', classifier: 'javadoc')
```